# Rails 5.1.5 PG 10.0.0 Getting PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function gen_random_uuid() does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Trying to use uuid in my new project.

Although I already enabled the extension by

```
enable_extension 'uuid-ossp'
```

I am still getting `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function gen_random_uuid() does not exist`.

I have been using uuid and postgres in rails 4.2.x without problem. Anyone has clue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails + Postgres migration - why am I receiving the error "PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function gen\_random\_uuid() does not exist"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064090/rails-postgres-migration-why-am-i-receiving-the-error-pgundefinedfunction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gen_random_uuid() is not in uuid-ossp but in pgcrypto

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/uuid-ossp.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/pgcrypto.html

So you need `enable_extension "pgcrypto"`