# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function gen_random_uuid() does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu, psycopg2

Error occurs when trying to run `python manage.py migrate` in a django application.
complete code

```
git clone https://github.com/saleor/saleor.git  
cd saleor  
python manage.py migrate
```

### Raised error
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function gen_random_uuid() does not exist
LINE 1: `UPDATE "account_user" SET "uuid" = GEN_RANDOM_UUID()`

but works in running postgres
I created extention in postgres, commited that.
Here is code to create extention in postgres and call the function which is raising the above error, so this function is working but I am unable to call through django when I use postgres db

```
postgres=# `SELECT gen_random_uuid()`;  
           gen_random_uuid
```

Output is

```
--------------------------------------  
 f36d69b7-5681-4b92-b37e-9b0217b7d829  
(1 row)
```

I tried to run this in docker and it works as expected

```
git clone https://github.com/saleor/saleor.git    
cd saleor  
python manage.py migrate
```

It works fine with docker.

I tried some other commands to check version and system, here
PostgreSQL 15.1 (Ubuntu 15.1-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, 64-bit Thanks for comment. –
Garuda

```
pg_lsclusters 
15 main 5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/15/main/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-15-main.log

----------------------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 15.1 (Ubuntu 15.1-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, 64-bit
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible you're running Django on a different server?

Comment: Thanks for comment.
But you can check settings.py , AFAIK this is not the real issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function gen\_random\_uuid() does not exist" on new server but not on old?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74527555/why-pgundefinedfunction-error-function-gen-random-uuid-does-not-exist-on)

Comment: You will have to check your Postgres version, as Postgres introduced this in version 13. Any version before this, you had to use external modules. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74527757/6383431

Comment: PostgreSQL 15.1 (Ubuntu 15.1-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, 64-bit

Thanks for comment.

Comment: pg_lsclusters
15  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/15/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-15-main.log

Comment: You will need to specify more about your setup, since in your original post you mention that `it doesn't work when running` and `but works in running` and `it works fine with docker`. There is also an issue on the Saleor-issue-tracker regarding this, you might have some success if you follow the workaround there. https://github.com/saleor/saleor/issues/10648#issuecomment-1249507171

Comment: It HAS to be the case that you're using two different servers here.  "gen_random_uuid" was added in Postgres 13.  Your Django app must be configured to use an older one.